# How to perform multiple noninferiority tests with linear mixed models?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, bonferroni, non-inferiority

I want to test a theory that predicts that certain measures are greater than or equal than others. Consequently, I want to perform noninferiority tests. Furthermore, I want to get rid of some confounders and random effects, and it seems that using linear mixed effects models is a good approach to do so. From what I read so far, I could determine the confidence interval for the treatment effect and see if it overlaps with the noninferiority interval.

To perhaps make it a bit more clear, this is my current R code:

```
fm1 <- lmer(formula, data = exp, REML=F)
print(fm1)
print(confint(fm1,method="boot"))
```

As I have to test multiple hypotheses, I would like to use Holm-Bonferroni correction. But the first step in Holm-Bonferroni is to sort the hypotheses by their p value. Just looking at the confidence intervals doesn't give me one. So how can I determine the p value? And more generally: Does the procedure make sense and are there other/better ways to reach my goal?